# Why is Rails ignoring validation when I run create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The simplified example is that I have several classes inheriting from an `Asset` class, which is an `ActiveRecord` model. When I use `create` or `create!` on one of the subclasses both the db layer and ActiveRecord layer validations for one field are ignored.

The Asset table has a `type` field with `null: false`, the Asset model has `validates_presence_of :type` and also has `attribute :type, default: self.name`.

If I use `new` on a subclass, such as Item, it behaves as expected, I get an `Item` with the `type` field set to `"Item"`. If I use `create` or `create!` with valid attributes, the defaults are not applied, validation is ignored and I get a persisted record with a `type` field of `nil`.

What's odd is that other validations are respected. If I try creating a new Item without a `name` attribute, `validates_presence_of :name` properly raises a validation error.

Here's some pared down code snippets for reference:

```rb
class CreateAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :assets do |t|
      t.string :type, null: false
      t.string :name
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: {
    Item: :Item,
    Accessory: :Accessory,
    Component: :Component,
    Consumable: :Consumable,
  }

  attribute :type, default: self.name

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :type
end
```

```rb
class Item < Asset
  # ...
end
```

```rb
i = Item.create({ ... })
i.type
#nil
i.persisted?
#true
i.valid?
#false
```

```rb
i = Item.new({ ... })
i.type
#"Item"
i.valid?
#true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'type' is a reserved column name in ActiveRecord because it is used to indicate [Single Table Inheritance](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance-sti) (STI) . If you are not intending to use STI you should pick a different column name otherwise the STI behaviors will interfere with what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Or put [`self.inheritance_column = nil`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema.html#method-c-inheritance_column) in the model.

Comment: When I read your comment I had a face palm moment, but upon implementation it turns out it doesn't fix this issue. I changed the field name to `asset_type`, but it's still `nil` when using `create`

Comment: Although, upon further inspection, it turns out I was trying to recreate STI on my own. I didn't realize Rails dealt with inheritance out of the box, I thought STI was a "programming concept" term, turns out it's an implementation. My problem was solved by simply removing all of my extra logic and using nothing but a `:type` field on the record. Thank you